# Who is the artist behind the mothership?

Tags: support, design, mothership

Who is the artist behind the mothership artwork shown on the top right of Arqade and Meta Arqade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was made by [Jin](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/jin). He used to be a designer for Stack Exchange (in fact he was THE designer), and actually did a lot (all?) of the site designs around that time. He was a regular on Arqade as well, and was actually one of our first users (which is why he has a user ID of 5!).

The original version of the Arqade Mothership used to shoot lasers when you hovered over it, which was just one of the many fantastic easter eggs Jin used to sneak into his designs. During the major network redesigns that occurred years ago, the lasers firing on hover functionality was sadly removed, and instead it just fires its lasers once per pageload.

In other words, Jin was basically the absolute best human being. Arqades main chat room, [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), still has [jin-fanclub](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jin-fanclub) as one of its roomtags to this day.

Comment: There are 2 things I miss the most: Christmas mornings when I was a child and the shooting laser mothership "ask question" button.